# How do I turn off functions that are used to print debug data in the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So there are several functions in my C++ program that "dump" data. This has immensly helped me to troubleshoot as I developed the application. The data is dumped into about a dozen ascii files.

Now I want that these functions not dump any data so I can see how fast the program can run and also, have a "final version" of the program.

Do I do something like this with all functions:

```
#define DO_DEBUG
#ifdef DO_DEBUG
void dump_dataA(...)
{
    // lot of code
}
#else
void dump_dataA(...)
{
    return;
}
#endif
```

I thinking along these lines since I cannot go back and remove all those lines where I dump data onto std::out and ascii files. That does not seem like a good idea. This is especially since if I have to upgrade this program later, all those lines will help me. So what is the best way to "turn off" the functions that are dumping debug data?

Comment: `That does not seem like a good idea.` why?

Comment: that seems alright, I was thinking about how "professionals" would do it. I am after all just an electronic engineer.

Answer (score 3):

Your way is possible, but arguments are evaluated, and implementation should be visible (in header). You may use preprocessor as follow:

```
#define DO_DEBUG

#ifdef DO_DEBUG
void dump_dataA_impl(/*args*/); // Implement it in cpp file or in header

# define dump_dataA(...) dump_dataA_impl(__VA_ARGS__)

#else
# define dump_dataA(...) /* Empty */
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (...something...) { CallDebugFunction(); } doNormalStuff();`. Would be the simple option. "something" could be an environment variable, something in a config file, a commandline argument or whatever you like..

Comment: This will waste running time each time the function is called. I'd prefer to use a preprocessor macro. :)

Comment: The overhead is going to be negligible - most likely - profile it if you are worried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the macro `_DEBUG` [defined by Visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/cpp/c-runtime-library/debug) when you set the compilation to Debug and it is not defined when the compilation type is Relase.

I'd also change the `#if-#else-#endif` blocks inside of the function something like this:

```
void dump_dataA(...)
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    cout << "data to log";
    #endif /*_DEBUG*/
}
```

Then, once you are ready to run the code with out debug just change the compilation type to *Release*

Here is a working example with `gcc` and `Makefile`

**Makefile:**

```
APP=test
release: clean comp_rel run
debug: clean comp_dbg run

clean:
    rm -rf ${APP}.exe

comp_dbg:
    gcc -D _DEBUG ${APP}.c -o ${APP}.exe
comp_rel:
    gcc  ${APP}.c -o ${APP}.exe

run:
    ./${APP}.exe > ${APP}.log
```

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    size_t i;
    while(i < 15)
    {
        i++;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        printf("Value: %d\n",i);
#endif

    }

    return 0;
}
```

To compile in debug mode:

```
make debug
```

This saves the output to `test.log`

To compile in release mode:

```
make release
```

And no output is stored in `test.log`